# Latex what symbol looks like letter I, Greek letter Iota, but is neither?

Tags: symbols

[image]

I'm looking for the symbol above but I can't find them anywhere. Could someone help me identify it?

Comment: That’s `\mathcal{I}`.

Comment: It's `\mathcal{I}` (Calligraphy letter I)

Comment: Thanks! Can you write an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one you are looking for is \mathcal{I}

Comment: Hm, that is already proposed in two comments ...